# Getting custom image size URL in functions

Tags: functions, images

I am trying to load `preload-thumb` into `data-pil-thumb-url` within the functions.php file so when a user edits a post with the TineyMCE it is automatically wrapped in a figure with the right classes. Whatever I do just returns blank.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'images_theme_setup' );
function images_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'preload-thumb', 300 ); // 300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
}

function html5_insert_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url) {
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url($id);
    $metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata ($id);
    $width = $metadata['width'];
    $height = $metadata['height'];
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $url, 'preload-thumb' );

  $html5 = "<figure id='post-$id media-$id' class='pil align-$align'>";
  $html5 .= "<img src='$url' alt='$title' data-pil-thumb-url='$image_attributes' data-full-width='$width' data-full-height='$height' />";
  $html5 .= "</figure>";
  return $html5;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html5_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

Comment: first argument for `wp_get_attachment_image_src` should be `$id`, not `$url`.